# Programmatically show next/previous image in stack widget

Tags: android, android-widget, android-appwidget, google-tv, stackview

I would like to enable a stack app-widget for Google TV.
The problem I'm having is that I need to show next and previous views programmatically.

I'm currently using a layout with a `StackView` and 2 Buttons. I can successfully receive the clicks of the buttons in my receiver but the method it's supposed to work is not doing anything

```
Toast.makeText(context, "next", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
remoteViews.showNext(R.id.stackWidgetView);
```

Debugging, the instance of `remoteViews` seams to be correct and the toast is triggered.

As I understand from the official documentation, the method `showNext(int)` of the `RemoteViews` should trigger the showNext of the `StackView`
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html#showNext(int)

The question is How can I trigger showNext() from the `AppWidgetProvider`

Answer (score 1):

Did you call `partiallyUpdateAppWidget` (API11+, but much nicer because you don't have to re-create your adapter, and with StackWidget you shouldn't worry about lower versions anyway) or `updateAppWidget` on the `AppWidgetManager` with your `remoteView`?

For reference, docs for AppWidgetManager: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetManager.html